# Adding a search bar to Folium Maps on Python

Tags: python

I used this code to add the search bar to my `folium` map:

```
from folium.plugins import Geocoder

Geocoder().add_to(m)
```

How do I modify it so that the search bar will only have those place names which I have with myself on an Excel sheet ?

I tried a lot of edits, but did not work.
I also tried using :

```
Cordinates=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Downloads/Project/QGIS Python/Dashboard/HOS_LOC_5.csv")
plugins.Search(Cordinates, search_zoom=6, geom_type="Polygon").add_to(map)
```